# What interfaces do all arrays implement in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, interface-implementation

As a new .NET 3.5 programmer, I started to learn LINQ and I found something pretty basic that I haven't noticed before:

The book claims every array implements `IEnumerable<T>` (obviously, otherwise we couldn't use LINQ to objects on arrays...). When I saw this, I thought to myself that I never really thought about that, and I asked myself what else all arrays implement - so I examined
`System.Array` using the object browser (since it's the base class for every array in the CLR) and, to my surprise, it doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

So my question is: where is the definition? I mean, how can I tell exactly which interfaces every array implements?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> [...] the Array class implements the `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`, `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces. **The implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and therefore are not visible to the documentation build tools.**

**EDIT:** as Jb Evain points out in his comment, only vectors (one-dimensional arrays) implement the generic interfaces. As to *why* multi-dimensional arrays don't implement the generic interfaces, I'm not quite sure since they do implement the non-generic counterparts (see the class declaration below).

The `System.Array` class (i.e. *every* array) also implements these non-generic interfaces:

```
public abstract class Array : ICloneable, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable
```

Comment: I would say: inherits this non-generic class, thus implements these non-generic interfaces

Comment: I hate to ask silly questions, then I really try to find my answer on MSDN first. This time I missed it... sorry for the trouble and thanks for the help.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but only vectors (one dimensional arrays) type implement the generic interfaces. A multi dimensional array type doesn't implement them.

Comment: @Jb Evain: Good point! It's also worth noting that jagged arrays do.

Comment: @Hosam Aly: Jagged arrays are nothing more than vectors who happen to contain other vectors. So there's no surprise here.

Answer (score 83):

You can find the answer to your question empirically using a small code snippet:

```
foreach (var type in (new int[0]).GetType().GetInterfaces())
    Console.WriteLine(type);
```

Running the above snippet would result in the following output (on `.NET 4.0`):

```
System.ICloneable
System.Collections.IList
System.Collections.ICollection
System.Collections.IEnumerable
System.Collections.IStructuralComparable
System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable
System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]
```

(`` `1 `` means `<T>`)

After `.NET 4.5` (`.NET Standard 1.0` and later), there's two additional interfaces:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Int32]
```

Comment: +1, though I would have used `typeof(int[])` rather than `(new int[0].GetType()`...

Comment: I like this. Also supports the quote from the MSDN docs (compare this with the output of iterating through `typeof(Array).GetType().GetInterfaces()`, where the generic implementations are missing).

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for the suggestion. I preferred to use `(new int[0]).GetType()` to make sure the result includes any *implementations provided to arrays at runtime*, as mentioned by @BoltClock.

Comment: Note that in .NET 4.5 (.NET Standard 1.0) they introduced two more, IReadOnlyList and IReadOnlyCollection.

Answer (score 57):

Starting with **.NET 4.5,** arrays also implement the interfaces [`System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385.aspx) and [`System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542.aspx).

Thus, when using .NET 4.5, the complete list of interfaces implemented by arrays becomes (obtained using the method presented in [Hosam Aly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4482679/455269)):

```cs
System.Collections.IList
System.Collections.ICollection
System.Collections.IEnumerable
System.Collections.IStructuralComparable
System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable
System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Int32]
```

Strangely, it seems that it was forgotten to update the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) to mention these two interfaces.

Comment: Your linked [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) contains this information, but a bit hidden: _"Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the `Array` class implements the `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`, `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces. The implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and as a result, the generic interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the Array class."_

Answer (score 1):

Carefully on array interfaces, they may implement them but actually they don't really do this... Take a loon on the following code:

```
            var x = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        var y = x as IList<int>;
        Console.WriteLine("The IList:" + string.Join(",", y));
        try
        {
            y.RemoveAt(1);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", y));
```

It produces the following output:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G61XU.png)

So parsing works but not everything is supported which is correct from fixed length collection perspective but quite wrong if you really believe that it is a list. There goes Liskov principle from SOLID :(.

For testing fast [this](http://rextester.com/YZHZ1945) will help.

Comment: Brilliant point.  I can see Microsoft's point of view, in that an array has a "Count", and is indexable.  But you're right, it can't implement RemoveAt(x) because that would mean re-dimensioning the array.  I guess that would be possible, as references to a variable can be moved by the CLR. - and without it, indeed Liskov substitution is out of the window.  The solution I guess would be to break down IList into IFixedList and IFlexibleList, and have Array implement only the IFixedList.  Still, I see the casting as a convenience in most cases.

Comment: Actually the IList<T> interface also has a property via ICollection<T> called IsReadOnly. A IList<T> implementation is therefor not required to actually handle the calls that manipulate the collection if IsReadOnly is returned as true, which it is for an Array.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the implementation of the `IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>` in the `SZArrayHelper` nested class of the Array.

But i have to warn you - there you will find much more questions...

[The refference](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,aa97964558672440)

After that i got only one - there_is_no_array ;)