# Instantiate new Array without language syntax []

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

In C# one can instantiate an Array with the special square bracket syntax `new int[3]`. This is different to other types which you instantiate by calling the constructor `new List<int>()`. Can you use the ordinary syntax to create an Array?

I tried `new System.Array<int>(3)` but it blows up

> The non-generic type 'System.Array' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: The error message is telling you that you can't do that.

Comment: No, you can't do that.  Why do you want to?

Comment: Not sure what you're after, but a "different" (but worse) way of doing it: `var newIntArray = (int[]) Array.CreateInstance(typeof (int), 10);`

Comment: you can try setting / creating a dynamic array.. when you declare the array declare it like this for example string[] myString = {}; then you can set the size based on the size of the List<int> for example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`System.Array` itself is abstract, so you won't be able to instantiate it using its constructor. And as evidenced by your error, it's not actually generic either; it only gets its type through [implementing generic collection interfaces at runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) (see also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4482567/106224)):

> #### Important
>
> In the .NET Framework version 2.0, the Array class implements the `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`, `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces. The implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and therefore are not visible to the documentation build tools.

For the above reasons, the `System.Array` class provides a convenience method called [`CreateInstance()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb3cfh7k.aspx) which you can use instead:

```
var array = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 3);
```

> #### Remarks
>
> Unlike most classes, `Array` provides the `CreateInstance` method, instead of public constructors, to allow for late bound access.

Be *very* careful when using this method, though, as the resultant `array` will *not* be strongly-typed at compile-time! If you want it to be strongly-typed you *must* cast it after creating it (and no, simply declaring `int[] array` won't be enough):

```
var array = (int[]) Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 3);
```

Comment: don't you need to assign that to something?

Comment: @Hunter McMillen: Psh. Added it in now.

Comment: there is another way of doing this as well by creating dynamic Array, then if the OP decides to use List<T> to hold the information the OP could assign the contents of the List<T>.ToArray() based on what he has declared dynamically {} I could post a working example if you would like to see.. Good Answer by the way BoltClock

Answer (score 1):

There's no "ordinary" constructor syntax to create an array. Your only choices are the array constructor syntax `new type[length]` and the various static `CreateInstance` methods of the `Array` class. Note that the latter are defined with the return type `Array`, which needs to be casted to the actual array type first.

BTW: `Array.CreateInstance` also allows you to create non-zero based arrays, which are otherwise unavailable to C#. Keep in mind, though, that almost nobody expects arrays and other IList implementations to have a lower bound other than zero.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use the following in c# if you want to assign values when instantiating the array.

predefinedIntArrayVariable = new int[]{x,y,z};

Comment: The OP is specifically asking if you can create an array *without* using that syntax.