# Why array do not have add and insert method

Tags: c#, arrays, list, insert, addition

Look into following code block:

```
string[] _array = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
List<string> _listArray = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };

//Why Invalid?
_array.Add("e");
_array.Insert(4, "e");

//Allowed for list.
_listArray.Add("e");
_listArray.Insert(4, "e");
```

Since both [`Array`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482557/what-interfaces-do-all-arrays-implement-in-c) and [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) implements almost same interface and use as collection of object then why `Array` dont have `Add` and `Insert` method

Comment: Array is a fixed size collection. If you can add or remove items to the Array the size will change and that violate the rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Almost** is a key here.

Array has fixed size and you can't add or insert new elements. You can change existing ones using `[]` array-index operator.

> The number of dimensions and the length of each dimension are established when the array instance is created. These values can't be changed during the lifetime of the instance.
>
> *from [Array (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx)*

And the fact that arrays implement certain interfaces with `Add` method, like `ICollection` does not change anything.

> The key thing to be aware of when you cast an array to one of these interfaces is that members which add, insert, or remove elements throw `NotSupportedException`.
>
> *from [`Array` Class (System)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx)*

Comment: Thanku for knowledgeable answer and array concepts.