# Return Type of Method Not Matching Type of Variable Returned, But Still Works

Tags: c#, collections, interface

I am trying to wrap my head around all the list Interfaces in C# (IEnumarable, IReadOnlyCollection) etc., and as part of that realized I do not really understand why the below code works. After all, the method has an *IReadOnlyCollection* as return type, but the varibale returned is of type Array (float[]). I realize that Array implements the IReadOnlyCollection interface, but I do not get how it converts from one to the other. Is it done in the background somehow?

```
private readonly float[] _location;

public Player()
{
    _location = new float[3];
}

public IReadOnlyCollection<float> Location
{
    get
    {
        _location[0] = Worker.Elements["lbXCoordinate"].Value;
        _location[1] = Worker.Elements["lbYCoordinate"].Value;
        _location[2] = Worker.Elements["lbZCoordinate"].Value;

        return _location;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no conversion - the returned `IReadOnlyCollection<float>` reference will be a reference to array itself. (And no, you shouldn't implement the property like this...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Jon, thanks for replying. I was trying to ensure that the consumer did not tamper with the outcome of the Property (it used to return a simple float[] before, but I realized that the Array could be written to). The fact that I write the variable in the get Accessor, is to ensure that whenever someone requests it, they get an updated value. Please see my other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506487/returning-array-in-property-if-setting-value-in-get-accessor. I would really appreciate it if you could explain what I should instead do. Thanks a million!

Comment: Well the caller can always cast back to the array type. I would suggest creating a *new* array on each call... or ideally, creating a separate struct with three properties instead of a collection at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet Funny you would say that, because prior to having float[] as return type, I had my struct Waypoint as return type. However, my program is making a call to this Accessor potentially more than once per second, so creating a new Waypoint (or new Array) instance everytime is going to hurt performance right? My Waypoint struct is fairly big. The post i linked to, explains it better.

Comment: "More than once per second" means pretty much nothing. Do you realize just how much you can do per second? But fundamentally, a struct that just has 3 `float` values in it should be okay - it's only 12 bytes, and it won't even be on the heap. Surely that's better than returning an array such that each call to `Location` will return the same reference, possibly changing the array for everyone else...

Comment: @JonSkeet I see, thanks! The Waypoint struct I can use does not just have three float values though, it also has a few methods like Distance(Waypoint w) and Angle(Waypoint w), as well overriding Equals and GetHashCode (it inherits from IEquatable<Waypoint>). Is it still OK you think? The Location will be requested from a while loop that runs continuously without any Thread.Sleep() or such to slow it down (thereby creating a new Waypoint instance over and over, very rapidly).

Comment: Having more methods is irrelevant - they don't take up space. As it's a struct, it will be created and returned on the stack, as far as we can see. But frankly, doing *anything* in a tight loop is a pretty bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object can be implicitly casted to any one of the interfaces that is implemented by its class; however, no *conversion* takes place - as Jon Skeet pointed out in a comment, it is the original array that is returned. To the caller, it will be "disguised" as an `IReadOnlyCollection<float>`, and the caller will ideally only perform operations from `IReadOnlyCollection<float>` on it. However, if the caller knows or suspects the actual type, the caller may decide to cast it back into a `float[]`, and the encapsulation of your object will be breached. (This is risky for the caller, though, since if you change the actual type to `List<float>` at some point, the code that casts to `float[]` will break.) In order to ensure encapsulation, the object that is returned must itself protect its contents, so you should indeed create a class/struct with private (or no) setters. Then, your code will become more readable and self-documenting as well.

Answer (score -1):

The above code works, because IReadOnlyCollection interface implements IEnumerable and Array abstract class also implements IEnumerable interface. So when you, return array of float for a method of IReadOnlyCollection return type, an upcasting is done internally to IEnumerable.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Is it not instead that the Array is up-casted to IReadOnlyCollection<float>, as Array implements that interface? When I look at the type of the variable that called Location, they are of type IReadOnlyCollection<float>, not IEnumerable.

Answer (score -1):

No, Array does not implement IReadOnlyCollection, please refer below link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx

And IReadOnlyCollection also implements same Interface IEnumerable, please refer below link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542(v=vs.110).aspx

Now, when you are trying to return an array for a method of type, IReadOnlyCollection, it is a type safe conversion to their base type which is IEnumerable.

Comment: Array does implement IReadOnlyCollection in .NET 4.5. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482557/what-interfaces-do-all-arrays-implement-in-c/18042379#18042379.