# Cast typed Ilist(Interface) to typed Array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I currently have an IList which is being constructed as followed:

```
var baseType = typeof(List<>);
Type genericType = baseType.MakeGenericType(prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First());
IList returnedvalues = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

Where `prop`refers to a property of an Object. For example

```
public List<String> PersonNames{get; set;}
```

or

```
public List<SomeSelfCreatedObject> MyObjects{get; set;}
```

Now the customers wants me to `return this Ilist as an Array`. I know how to return it as an `Object[] or any other predefined type(like Int,String)`. But is it possible to return as Array of the type defined in the code above?

so I would have the following output (after cast)

```
public List<SomeSelfCreatedObject> MyObjects{get; set;} 
             Would result in => SomeSelfCreatedObject[]
public List<String> PersonNames{get; set;} 
             Would result in => String[]
```

Comment: You can return an array of the expected type but still the compile time type can't be of `T[]`. You can make run time type as `T[]` not compile time type. because you don't even know the type at compile time.

Comment: Answer is simple. You need another reflection invoke to call the `ToArray` of `List<T>` or just call `Enumerable.ToArray` using reflection directly.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Just posted an answer to that effect using `dynamic`. Its a bit simpler than writing the reflection out yourself. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type returned by `Activator.CreateInstance(genericType)` is of the type `List<T>` where `T` is unknown at compile time. This makes casting tricky. We can use `dynamic` here and the direct call to `Enumerable.ToArray()` to get the value as `T[]`.

```
dynamic returnedvalues = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
dynamic valuesAsArray = Enumerable.ToArray(returnedvalues);
```

We still can't know the type of `valuesAsArray` at compile time which makes it tricky to use but I don't know if this will be a problem for you or not. It depends on what you want to do with it next...

As Sriram Sakthivel points out in comments you can cast valuesAsArray to something non-dynamic. It can never be a generic type because you don't know the compiletime type but you could cast to Array or any number of other things (see [What interfaces do all arrays implement in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482557/what-interfaces-do-all-arrays-implement-in-c) for info on what else you could cast it to).

Comment: `valuesAsArray` could be `dynamic` or `IList` or even base class `Array` based on what OP needs to do with it. But this will work as expected. If OP needs the data also, he can just call `ToArray` on source list directly. +1

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Yeah, it could be cast to a non-generic type as you say have added a paragraph to that effect. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @User999999: A thousand extra rep would be nice but I'll be happy enough with that reaction. ;-)

Comment: @User999999 Be sure that you understand what that magic keyword `dynamic` does before using it, otherwise, you'll regret later. If you already know how that works, just disregard my comment.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I'm currently reading up on it. Thought  I understood it, but after this, i know i have to do some extra studying.

Comment: The simple answer on what dynamic does is that any time you use a dynamic thing it will go into a big ball of reflection and thus be inefficient. :) Only use it if you really really don't know what the type is at compile time and where possible Explicitly cast your result to something non-dynamic to prevent propogation of dynamic to everything it touches. :) But yes, its a big topic that you could make sure you understand. :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question, can't you just call the ToArray() method on your List?

Comment: IList doesn't have a definition of `ToArray() `

Comment: `IList` doesn't have a suitable method on it and `Activator.CreateInstance` returns an `Object` which also has no suitable method.

Comment: @User999999 Don't use IList. You already know your type is List<>. You can reliably use reflection to find and call the ToArray method.

Comment: I see now.  You can still use the ToArray method taking Sriram's suggestion to either create a List first or use Enumerable.ToArray