# How to use ToString to display object types in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, tostring

I have an array with different types of objects, for example:

```
Object[] array = {"String_1", double 3.14, "String_2"};
```

I want to override `ToString()` so when I use it on the array above it will show object class types and how many of them are in the array, for example:

```
Object[] array = {"String_1", double 3.14, "String_2"};

Console.WriteLine(array.ToString()); // will print "String-2,Double-1"
```

---

Would like some help with doing this :-)

Comment: Break the problem down - how would you _group_ the objects in the array by their _type_? And then how would you _count_ them?

Comment: To be clear, you can't do this with `array.ToString()` (where array is the original array). You have to write some other code.

Comment: Why would you want to build / print a string instead of properly using a dictionary?

Comment: You don't particularly need to use a dictionary @OneCricketeer - although that is one way yes.

Comment: `string.Join(",", array.GroupBy(c => c?.GetType(), (c, i) => $"{c?.Name ?? "null"}-{i.Count()}"))` which can be simpler if you know you won't have nulls

Comment: @mjwills yeah thanks. I've mentioned that I need to override the original ToString()..

Comment: @MichaelOlari Why do you want to override `ToString`? Who told you to do it that way? You don't have the ability to change `object[]`'s `ToString` method. _I mean you might be able to do it with some advanced techniques - but that is very much the wrong technique to use here._

Comment: @mjwills It's an assignment I've got in c# course. I actually managed to it(I was supposed to do it in a custom class of the Object array) :-). Thank you very much for all the tips and info!

Comment: A custom class can work yes. But not `array.ToString()` _specifically_ (where array is the input array).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write your own `ToString` implementation for a class you do not own, and you do not own the `Array` class.

You'll need to write your own method that converts the array to your preferred format. Fortunately this is pretty straightforward with LINQ. We can even make it an extension method so it feels more *natural*:

```cs
using System.Linq;

public static class ArrayExt
{
   public static string ToCustomString(this object[] array) 
   {
      var grouped = array.GroupBy(
         c => c?.GetType(), 
         (type, vals) => $"{type?.Name ?? "null"}-{vals.Count()}"
      );
      var result = string.Join(",", grouped);
      return result;
   } 
}
```

And an example of its usage:

```cs
object[] array = new object[] { 1, 2, "Three", 4.0f, "Five", 6M }; 
// extension method syntax 
var value1 = array.ToCustomString();
// or static invocation sytanx
var value2 = ToCustomString(array);
```

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRj1UwAJUCA6AGQEsoBHAbjzwHsAjAKwFMBjYAG0AuqQCGYMGICepALykoPAO6lOvAaREBvAjFLp9AIgAWPADbm2R/ekqYAZvoIBZY8rZhzcI6QC+LLh4AG4SpADmYGwQAA48cPLikjKUAOJRsQBC0gAUfPIAfKR8APxpPMAAKtJxOQCU+nn6tHWFpAAkRtqllAByYgC2PKQlJaRGUBCWRn4AtNq0lADC0VDA9X5GdYGhYKRgPADOU8CJFJiUAFJs9Dk2NhEZcXDbxAQAnDkHx+bA20A==)

This groups the individual items in the array by their `Type` or `null` using [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____2__). Each group is transformed such that we now have a collection where each item is a string in the format `"{TypeNameOrNull}-{Count}"`. We then pass this to [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__) to build a combined string, delimiting each item with a comma.

If you know you won't have `null`s in your array, we can simplify the above to:

```cs
var grouped = array.GroupBy(
   c => c.GetType(),
   (type, vals) => $"{type.Name}-{vals.Count()}"
);
var result = string.Join(",", grouped);
```

If you (for example) want the final string ordered by the number of items per type/group, you'd need a more verbose version, combining `GroupBy` with [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) and [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__):

```cs
var groupedAndOrdered = array
    .GroupBy(
       c => c.GetType(), 
       (type, vals) => new { Name = type.Name, Count = vals.Count() }
    )
    .OrderBy(c => c.Count)
    .Select(c => $"{c.Name}-{c.Count}");
var result = string.Join(",", groupedAndOrdered);
```

If you don't like the built-in type names (`Single` instead of `float`, `Int32` instead of `integer`) you'd need to write a method that included the logic to turn them into your preferred text:

```cs
public static string TypeToName(Type type) {
    if (type == null) return "null";
    if (type == typeof(float)) return "float";
    if (type == typeof(int)) return "int";
    // etc 
    return type.Name; // fallback 
}
```

Which you can then use when constructing the string, for example:

```cs
var grouped = array.GroupBy(
   c => c?.GetType(),
   (type, vals) => $"{TypeToName(type)}-{vals.Count()}"
);
var result = string.Join(",", grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

For overriding, you need to derive from an array type. But you cannot even derive from array types in the first place. Even if you make `ToString()` an extension method, the default `ToString()` method will always be prioritized over an extension method. Your only option here is to create a custom array type with an overriden `ToString()`.

```
public class CustomArray
{
    private object[] array;

    public CustomArray(int size) => array = new object[size]; 

    public CustomArray(object[] array) => this.array = array;
    
    public object this[int index] { get => array[index]; set => array[index] = value; } //Indexer 
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
          var dict = new Dictionary<Type, int>();
          foreach (var item in array) 
          {
              Type type = item.GetType();
              if (dict.ContainsKey(type)) 
              {
                  dict[type]++;
              } 
              else
              {
                 dict[type] = 1;  
              }
          }
          return string.Join(", ", dict.Select(item => $"{item.Key.Name}: {item.Value}"));
          
    } 
}
```

Of course, you can go more in depth and make your custom array implement `IEnumerable<T>`, `ICollection<T>` and other interfaces(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4482567/11455105) answer) to make it more identical to the inbuilt array type.

Answer (score -1):

Why you need to override the `ToString`?

Instead, write a function to `StringfyObjectArray` and `Map` the values in the desired format.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment. You can make it an answer quite easily.

Comment: it's an assignment I've got in c# course :-)